# How do I get a unique list of files modified in a repository within a range of commits in Git?

Tags: git

I would like to obtain a list of files from a git repository that have been modified or created within a range of commits. Is this possible? I've taken a look at `log` but it doesn't seem to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git diff --name-only ${range}` will give you exactly what you want: only the names of files modified in this time.

Actually, it gives you almost what you asked for: this would include files that were completely deleted, not just modified files.  It would also miss files that were created, then removed, within the range.

To get the complete picture you would probably want to walk the range and then uniq the results; use `git log` to get the range of commits, then diff each against the parent.

Comment: Though diff does accept ranges (`commit..commit`) the more natural syntax is two arguments, `git diff [opts] commit1 commit2`, which makes it clear it's showing you the difference between the two, not doing anything with the commits between.

Answer (score 4):

```
git diff --stat SHAstart..SHAend
```

will give you a list of files changed between the SHAIDs SHAstart and SHAend

Answer (score 1):

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM <REV1>..<REV2>`

This will give a list of files (`--name-only`) modified or added (`--diff-filter=AM`) in all commits reachable after  and before  (`<REV1>..<REV2>`) where  and  is a revision in git.

For more information about specifying revisions and ranges see this page: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rev-parse.html

For more information about the diff options and especially the `--diff-filter` options see: http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-diff